# Options to export a polygon defined in ArcGIS SDK for .NET WPF into a KML file?

Tags: arcgis-runtime-sdk-wpf, arcgis-runtime-sdk-.net

Using ArcGIS SDK for .NET WPF.

I have a ArcGIS SDK for WPF user interface that allows users to create polygons on a map.

What are my options to export the ploygon shape as a KML or SHP file?

I saw [examples showing how to read and display KML](https://developers.arcgis.com/net/latest/wpf/sample-code/displaykml.htm) files. But I am looking to export my plygons to KML (or SHP) files

If the ArcGIS SDk cannot directly export to KML, I am fine with running another tool or SDk to export in memory plygon data into an KML file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ArcGIS Runtime does not currently support generating/editing KML files or creating new shapefiles.
Your best bet is look at the KML Specification and just write out the little bit of XML that is required to create a KML file with a polygon in it.
KML Reference: https://www.bing.com/search?q=kml+reference&PC=U316&FORM=CHROMN

Comment: Thank you for your help. Do you know if there is any command line tool or SDK that converts polygon waypoints to a KML file? The reason that I prefer not to create my own code is that I concern the units in ArcGIS and KML are not the same and I fall into Long/Lat unit conversation. I am not a string GIS developer, and I do not have lots of time to build the application.

Comment: The units in KML are fixed (wgs84 lat/long), and ArcGIS will read them and project accordingly.